# Converting a String to Date and raising an exception when given String is invalid

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

Here is my code given below. I want if the date given is incorrect it should display a message that is "The format provided is incorrect".

But I cant get it to raise the exception.
Is the exception used incorrect which other exception provided by oracle can I use for this case?

```
Create or Replace Procedure A1SF_TESTDATE
(
    pDateStr Varchar2
)As
    tDate Date;
    Begin
    tdate := TO_DATE(pDateStr, 'yyyymmdd');
    dbms_output.put_line(tdate);
    Exception 
      When INVALID_NUMBER Then
        dbms_output.put_line('The format provided is incorrect');

End;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many exception which can be thrown by the `TO_DATE` function. Examples:

- ORA-01843 - Invalid month value
- ORA-01847 - Invalid day value
- ORA-01830 - date format picture ends before converting entire input string
- ...

You can catch them as in the following example (with only one exception):

```
Create or Replace Procedure A1SF_TESTDATE
(
    pDateStr Varchar2

    -- you must do this for every oracle exception number which will you catch
    bad_month EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (bad_month, -01843);
)As
    tDate Date;
    Begin
    tdate := TO_DATE(pDateStr, 'yyyymmdd');
    dbms_output.put_line(tdate);
    Exception 
      When bad_month Then
        dbms_output.put_line('The format provided is incorrect');

End;
```

But for that you must define *n* pragmas!

The easier solution, which I prefer, is:

```
Create or Replace Procedure A1SF_TESTDATE
    (
        pDateStr Varchar2
    )As
        tDate Date;
Begin
        tdate := TO_DATE(pDateStr, 'yyyymmdd');
        dbms_output.put_line(tdate);
        Exception 
          -- every exception will be catched
          When others Then
            dbms_output.put_line('The format provided is incorrect! Because: ' || SQLERRM);

 End;
```

A possible message for `SQLERRM` is `ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month`.

Comment: If I want this to be a Function so that It returns the DBMS output line as a String, what changes have to be made?

Comment: I think you don't want a string! I suppose that you need an exception which you can catch outside your function! How do you use your function? In an other function or an SQL statement?

Comment: Great! I update my conversion function to catch day and year exceptions : `bad_month EXCEPTION;
PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (bad_month, -01843);
bad_day EXCEPTION;
PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (bad_day, -01847);
bad_year EXCEPTION;
PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (bad_year, -01841);
`