# pl/sql block going in infinite loop

Tags: plsql

```
create or replace
function f_amt(date_in in varchar2) return number 
as 
BEGIN 
DECLARE 
   v_at            ES.AMT%TYPE; 
   i                number := 0;
   BEGIN 

      v_at := 0;
      WHILE v_at = 0 
      LOOP
        BEGIN
        select nvl(AMT,0) 
        into v_at 
        from es 
        where date1 = to_date(date_in,'MM/DD/YYYY') - i; 
        i := i + 1;    
        EXCEPTION when NO_DATA_FOUND 
        then
        v_at:=0; 
      END;
      END LOOP;
      RETURN v_at; 
   END; 
EXCEPTION 
  WHEN OTHERS THEN 
     RETURN 0;
END;
```

ES table has date and amount, and I want to amount as o/p for latest date available in ES for date given.

Eg:
If date_in='20160223' and amount in ES is available for '20160220', then this amt should be returned in v_at and above while loop should exit. But it is going infinitely. Please suggest the correction in code required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens if there is no prior value?

Wouldn't it be simpler, faster (and safer) to do:

```
select AMT
into v_at
from es
where date1 = (
   select max(date1)
   from es
   where date1 <= to_date(date_in,'MM/DD/YYYY')
         and AMT is not NULL
         and AMT <> 0)
```

There is no loop, only two index seeks (provided there is an index on date1).
Also you don't mention if date1 is unique (but your code would also fail if not).

Answer (score 1):

change:

```
EXCEPTION when NO_DATA_FOUND 
        then
        v_at:=0;
```

with:

```
EXCEPTION when NO_DATA_FOUND 
        then
        exit;
```

Infinite loop happens, because at some i there is always no_data_found exception and v_at is always 0. You can write it

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_amt (date_in IN VARCHAR2)
   RETURN NUMBER
AS
BEGIN
   FOR c1 IN (  SELECT amt
                  FROM es
                 WHERE date1 <= TO_DATE (date_in, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
                   AND nvl(amt,0) <> 0
              ORDER BY date1 DESC)
   LOOP
      RETURN c1.amt;
   END LOOP;

   RETURN 0;
END;
```

Try not to use EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS.  When OTHERS happens, you want to see it. And if a function is often called, try to avoid exceptions. They have to be actually exception. They are expensive. When you expect NO_DATA_FOUND, instead of select into open cursor and use %NOTFOUND or use for loop.

Comment: It is good advice not to use `WHEN OTHERS` because we would also swallow exceptions when `date1` is renamed to `date2` for instance and thus never know why the function always returns 0 suddenly. However, `WHEN OTHERS` is obviously used here to catch all the possible `TO_DATE` exceptions. So as long as it shall be part of the function's task to return 0 on invalid date strings something like a broad exception handling is needed. Here is a thread dealing with exactly this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9836508/converting-a-string-to-date-and-raising-an-exception-when-given-string-is-invali

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I see, but I don't think, that if you pass this function a date '20160223' and you expect a  'MM/DD/YYYY' format, will be a good idea to swallow this exception

Comment: You are right; the caller should be informed that the given date string is considered invalid. That would be much better. It boils down to: The function is validating the date string and getting the AMT in case it is valid. This should be two separate tasks instead.

Comment: The interface design is bad IMO. The function currently converts an ambiguous date string (which you just have to know) _and_ returns a value for the resulting date, so it's doing two things, one of them implicit. To do its validation job properly it should check the date string thoroughly (maybe a regex and some explicit named exceptions) although even then you could pass `01/02/2016` when you meant `02/01/2016` and there's no way it could tell. It would be far better to require an actual date. I expect a string was just easier for the OP to code in the front end.

Answer (score 0):

In case there is no `date1 <= date_in` you will search on forever. In order to find the last `amt` for `date1 <= date_in` you should use Oracle SQL's `keep dense_rank last`.

```
create or replace function f_amt(date_in in varchar2) return number as 
  v_amt es.amt%type; 
begin 
  select max(amt) keep (dense_rank last order by date1)
  into v_amt
  from es
  where date1 <= to_date(date_in,'mm/dd/yyyy')
  and amt <> 0; 

  return v_amt; 
exception when others then 
  return 0;
end;
```

As you see, the PL/SQL function is only needed now to react on invalid date strings. Otherwise pure SQL would suffice. You may want to consider validating the date string somewhere else in PL/SQL (and give a proper error message in case it is invalid) and then use the mere SQL query with the date got instead of a PL/SQL function. (See also Mottor's comment on `WHEN OTHERS` and my answer to that.)

Comment: There's an extra `begin declare` at the top (doubtless copied from the OP).

Comment: Yes, thanks William, I didn't spot this when copying the code. I've corrected this now.